# property for list<T>

Tags: c#

```
List<T> lst = new List<T>();

public List<T> List
{
    get { return lst; }
    set { //cod...???????????????????? }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Mah, what's your question?  Should I have a set implementation?  Should I clear lst, then copy all items from value into lst?  Bunch of different ways to look at this - we need you to be more descriptive of what you're asking.

Comment: I'm assuming you are asking how to use the setter of a property?

Comment: question...????????????????????

Answer (score 5):

```
List<T> lst = new List<T>();

public List<T> List
{
    get { return lst; }
    set { lst = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases like this, you do *not* want a setter, effectively making the list itself read-only. In other words, anybody can change the contents of the list, but you can never give an instance of the object a new list.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above it looks like you want the setter to copy all items over, in which case you would do this:

```
private List<T> lst;

public List<T> List {
    get { return lst; }
    set { lst = new List<T>(value); }
}
```

But if that's all you want, I would recommend just using an auto property, to wit:

```
public List<T> MyList { get; set; }
```

Of course this raises issues of encapsulation, as Gabe pointed out.

Comment: Note, my answer clears the list and sets it to what was sent, and Akash Kava's answer appends the contents onto the list.  Not sure which one you want.  If it's the latter (appending items), then I would strongly urge you to make the setter private, and provide a *method* for your client to use to append items onto your list.

Answer (score 1):

Most often I would recommend that properties of a collection type do not have a public Set so they don't allow changing the actual collection object reference, only modify the collection. Otherwise it can lead to confusing problems if a user saves the reference to the collection and then in another part of the code sets the property to another collection. The first usage then have a reference to something that the class containing the property is not using.

```
public List<T> List { get; private set;}

public MyClass()
{
    this.List = new List<T>();
}
```

or, depending on when and how you want to define your collection...

```
private List<T> list = new List<T>();
public List<T> List { get { return list; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<T> lst = new List<T>();

public List<T> List
{
    get { return lst; }
    set { lst.AddRange(value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply encapsulate it using Studio. ;)

[image]